# In pyaudio, how can I get a stream to 'consistently' produce sound?

Tags: pyaudio

I am using an endless *while* loop to convert byte data (used in single chunks), to an integer value (in order to 'manipulate' those values and then reconvert the values back to bytes again and write the bytes to the PyAudio stream (for sound).

Everything plays smoothly *until* I write a complex function that takes up too much processing time. Then, I hear a bunch of pops, snaps and clicks over the audio. I notice that the reason for this happening, is because (between the time that the program loops to play the next chunk of streamed data provided to the PyAudio stream), there is a 'transition' of silence *as* there is a 'wait' for the loop to repeat... and that is what creates the pops between each chunk being played *if* the loop is 'too slow'.

Is there a way to make the 'voltage' going to the speakers at 'constant' based on the *last* data value provided to the PyAudio's stream? This would be a great way to smoothen out the 'pops', 'snaps' and 'clicks' when playing sound, instead of there being silence *until* the next value is passed to the stream. The reason I don't use a chunk greater than 1, is because I want to do many 'creative' things with PyAudio (through an endless loop), and have values inside the loop determine the 'voltage level' going to the speakers.

Comment: You can use separate threads to generate the data and tend to the stream

Comment: That's a good idea, but I just found out that another workable solution (for some reason), was to use multiple lines of stream.write(data) instead of just 1 line. It was a 'workaround' around the problem.